# Watson Assistant plugin in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, chatbot, ibm-watson, intermittent

The Watson Assistant chatbot on my Wordpress site (https://soans.intelaedu.com) keeps freezing and I have to keep refreshing the chatbot through the plugin setup by clicking on the button "Save Changes" located in Wordpress.  For my plugin setup, I use an API key (screenshot below) as I do not have a Username/Password.  Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[screen capture of the Watson Assistant plugin setup in Wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcTBb.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of the plugin? IIRC there should be a support site for that plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry about the delay in getting back to you.  Yes did contact someone from IBM and the issue appears to be resolved now.

Comment: Make sure to document the solution so others can see.